Ratio of Gaussian Quadratic Form
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be a symmetric and PSD matrix. Let $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{I}_d)$ be an istropic Gaussian random variable. I am interested in an upper bound on
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{(Z^\top A Z)^2}{Z^\top A^2 Z} \right].
\end{equation}
Notice that $\mathbb{E}\left[Z^\top A Z\right]=\mathrm{Tr}(A)$ is the trace of $A$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[Z^\top A^2 Z\right]=\|A\|_F^2$ is the squared Frobenius Norm of $A$. In particular, I want to show an upper bound that depends on $\mathrm{Tr}(A)/\|A\|_F^2$.

Because of the isotropy, wiithout loss of generality you can assume $A=\mathrm{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_n).$ Now $$E\left(\frac{(a_1Z_1^2+\cdots+a_nZ_n^2)^2}{a_1^2Z_1^2+\ldots+a_n ^2Z_n^2}\right)= \int_0^{\infty}E\left((a_1Z_1^2+\cdots+a_nZ_n^2)^2)e^{-s(a_1^2Z_1^2+\ldots+a_n ^2Z_n^2)}\right)ds.$$ You can rather work with this integral, since the last expectation can be made explicit.
